# Postgresql - does it make sense to transform tree to graph

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgresql, and cascade soft delete trigger

Before we start, I would like to attach trigger

```
create or replace function cascade_soft_delete()
returns trigger as $$
declare
  parent_column text := TG_ARGV[0];
begin
    if (TG_OP = 'UPDATE' and (new.deleted_at is not null or new.deleted_at is null)) then
      for i in 1..(TG_NARGS-1) loop
        execute format('update %I.%I set deleted_at = $1 where %I = $2 and deleted_at is null', TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_ARGV[i], parent_column) using new.deleted_at, old.id;
        end loop;
        return old;
    end if;
    return null;
end;
  $$ language plpgsql;
```

I have a database structure in the tree view.

For example I have `Human->Work->Country->Planet`, `Human->Country->Planet`, `Human->Family->Wife` and so on, and I have cascade soft delete trigger, so for example if I delete `Human` database should delete `Family` and then `Wife`, and so on if I'm not wrong it will cause a O(N) time complexity, and O(K) space complexity, as it happens in the traverse binary tree.

I would like to hear does it triggers works in the same way, does it cause a recursion?

Also, if I will transform this tree to the directed graph will it help me, for example I will go from the end to the root and from the root I will go the end and repeat the previous steps, until I will not go to the start of the graph

Also maybe I have some issues in the trigger, because now for about 20K records, which a squeeze out between several related tables, for delete root record, `explain analyze` show me 110K ms sometimes it can take a more time, a max time which I saw it was a 440K ms, which is so long as for me. Database configuration is a 2 CPUs and 4GBs RAM, also I'm not exclude that these configuration is can't cope with this load